# ember app within another ember app

Tags: ember.js

We are writing Ember app which provides basic infrastructure for app building. Users can use this app and build there own Ember app by utilizing infrastructure provided by this app. This app provides basic utility services like Authorization, Authentication, layout, templates, reusable UI components, consistent look and feel, scaffolding, dependency stack etc. My question is,

How can users build there own Ember app utilizing these services and include it within this parent app, something like nested app, where parent app provides common services. Is it possible to include one Ember app within another Ember app? child app content should be shown in parent content window retaining all navigation links and layout.

There can also be a situation where multiple apps are included under parent app and each of these child app can be accessed using a router in parent app, example, if child1 and child2 apps are included under parent app, then navigating to "/childRoute1" of parent should open child1 in parent content window and navigating to "childRoute2" should open child2 in content window. Is this possible using Ember? if not how this can be achieved?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit vague, but I think what you want:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#ember-app'
});
```

Include that within the Ember.js Application definition to assign an Ember app to a specific div (in this case `ember-app`).  This div can be within the jsp of another existing Ember.js application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The approach you suggested only works if we need to include ember app with in other (non ember) apps, it does not work if we want to include ember app within another ember app. Ember does not allow this and throws assertion fail error saying rootElement is part of ember app.